# If statement does not work as intended

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement

I want to make sure that none of the variables (`name`, `adres`, `code`, etc) are `nil`. Here is what I've tried:

```
if (name == nil && adres == nil && code == nil && place == nil && telNr == nil && mail == nil) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"EXAMPLE"
                                                    message:@"EXAMPLE "
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

} else { //do the rest }
```

The problem is that when one of the variables is not nil, it runs the else statement, however I want to make sure none of the variables is nil.

I tried `|` instead of `&&` but its worse then of course.

Comment: You code checks if _all_ of them are `nil`. If you want to check to see if _any_ of them are `nil`, you use the `||` operator (not the `|` operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical `OR` (`||`) should have worked. It's like saying, if any of these are `nil` show popup, if none are, go to else branch.

If you actually used `|` and not `||`, note that `|` is the bitwise-inclusive operator, not the logical one.

Comment: tnx! that was the answer. i dont know why its closed you got the picture :)